# R Shiny Randomly Generated Radio Button Choices

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a survey in Shiny where I want the choices as represented by radio buttons to be randomly drawn. See sample code below:

```
library(shiny)

choices<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
x1<-sample(choices,2)
x2<-sample(choices,2)

ui<-fluidPage(
     radioButtons("q1","Which do you prefer?", choices=c(x1,"No Preference"),selected=""),
     radioButtons("q2","Which do you prefer?", choices=c(x2,"No Preference"),selected="")),

server <- function(input, output) {
# Not important
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run the app locally a different set of choices will be selected each time I run the app (as intended). But once I publish to shinyapps.io the choices are the same each time (as in `x1` is the same each time I run the app). How can I make so that each time the app opens a new sample is taken from the choice set?

Comment: alternatively, could you call `set.seed(Sys.time())` at the app's initialization to randomize your seed each session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, Shiny server implements caching to improve system utilization. The problem you are having is the `x1` variable is being sampled and cached between users.

The way around this problem is to sample choices into a `reactiveValue` and then dynamically update the radio buttons when the page loads.

Alternatively, you might try using [this approach](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1882):

```
ui <- function(req) {
  fluidPage(
   x1<-sample(choices,2)
   x2<-sample(choices,2)
   radioButtons("q1","Which do you prefer?", choices=c(x1,"No Preference"),selected=""),
   radioButtons("q2","Which do you prefer?", choices=c(x2,"No Preference"),selected=""))
   ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue of randomizing radio buttons, but it created a different issue. When I define ```x1``` in the ui function, can I use ```x1``` when defining the ```server```?

Comment: I don't believe you can. That's why I recommended updating the radio button from your server function at startup.